# The font on a gold tag badge alert thing is not the correct font

Tags: bug, status-completed, dupehammer

[image: TNR FTW]

I don't think that Times New Roman is the intended font, but if it is, then [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) I guess.

I'm running Chrome 55.0.2883.87, Windows 10, and my JavaScript is V8 5.5.372.32.